# Can I limit a user to only be able to upload a file to a single directory via scp?

Tags: debian, security, sshd

I would like to create a ci user on a device to allow for a pipeline to drop a file into a single directory only.

I have created a user using:

```
useradd -M -N -r -s /bin/false devops
chown -R devops /var/file-drop/
```

For authentication, I have the following line in my `sshd_config`

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/my-org.root.pub
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/authorized_principals/%u
```

and have added a file called `devops` with content `devops` in the authorized_principals directory.

My question is: excluding any 0-day vulnerabilities and such, does the above setup actually achieve my goal of allowing a user with that principal only access to dropping a file in `/var/file-drop`? Or am I inadvertently opening up other attack surfaces by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chroot to "lock" the user to a diretory

```
Match User devops
ChrootDirectory /var/file-drop/
```